# Why is my text not breaking at all?

Tags: html, css

I have kept trying over ands over to break my text but for some reason its just not working at all. All i want is to have a width for my text when i type into the document.

**HTML**

```
<div class="vid-content">

        <div class="vid-content-vids">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/vids.png" class="videos" style="height:150px; width:150px;"></a>
        <a href="#"><h>Carlton is called a sellout</h></a>
        </div>

  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.vid-content-vids h {
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bolder;
font-size: 15px;
word-wrap: break-all;
width: 30px;
margin-left: 10%;

}
.vid-content-vids {
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: .5%;
padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.vid-content-vids img {

position: relative;
left: 18%;
}
```

Comment: <h>Carlton is called a sellout</h> do you mean <h1, h2,..>

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want a line break at a specific point in your text?

Comment: i just want the text to break but it wont

Comment: nevermind i fixed it, i had to write h1 thank you coderomeos

Comment: Unclear what you mean. If I take your code and set the `.vid-content-vids` value of `width: 150px` instead of `width: 200px`, the text breaks (wraps).

Answer (score 0):

For your `.vid-content-vids` class you setup `width: 200px`. Try to change this value, to make you text in one line.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
.vid-content-vids a h {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 15px;
    word-wrap: break-all;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of how/why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.